# iText 7 reorder logical structure elements

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'll make it short. I need to reorder the logical structure elements in a pdf using iText 7 because of the order for screen readers. Is there any way to reorder existing logical structure elements?

I already tried getting the `PdfStructTreeRoot` but it only has methods for adding new kids.

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(inputFile), new PdfWriter(outputFile));
PdfStructTreeRoot rootTree = pdfDoc.GetStructTreeRoot();
```

Is there a build-in way to reorder the elements?

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment. I feared that there is not build-in way. The "Read aloud" function is the reason why I need to reorder the elements, because the order of the read text is incorrect. I will take a closer look into the PDF specification.

Comment: To make the "Read aloud" work properly, you need a properly tagged document. See about tagging in itext: https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/pdfhtml-accessible-pdf-creation